# Deploying ASP MVC 5 App with IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, asp.net-mvc-5

I try to deploy ASP MVC 5 app in virtual directory (without creating new iis application) 
I use IIS 7.5

I already put

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
<directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
```

in web.config file.
But when i go to app url with IE browser it shows me just directory listing like in screenshot below

[image]

Is there a way to deploy MVC 5 in virtual directory and make it work like usual MVC application?

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the virtual directory to application. Right click on it in the IIS management console and choose `Convert To Application...`. Also make sure that the associated application is configured to use Integrated Pipeline Mode.

Comment: I know that i can do it with "Convert To Application". But i need to deploy my app exactly in virtual directory. Cause it will be part of another application (and i dont want to sharing session between different applications)

Comment: A virtual directory cannot execute ASP.NET applications. It can only contain some static files. If you want to execute ASP.NET code you need an application in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem earlier in my production environment by checking the directory pointer in IIS.  Apparently when I unzipped the deployed site from one server to the next, the zip utility made an extra level, so IIS was pointing to /MyProject when the files were in /MyProject/MyProject.  I had a little better clue though, you have Document Browsing enabled based on that screen shot, make sure not to do that in production.  I set the site to log custom errors and got a 403.14 response, from there found a blog on my mistake.  You need to setup the environment to find the specific module that's failing, I think something to do with trace routes, idk.  I'm a software developer that always gets forced into doing devOps; was googling my own problem and thought I'd throw you a line.  Without a specific error message, all I can tell you is IIS is not connecting to .NET; something is not configured correctly.  Turn off directory browsing, google how to get good error logs back, and let us know the status code so we can help you: 403.14, 401, 500, 404?  Also give us the module that's failing.  If it's the last one on the handler list, guess what, IIS isn't connecting to the app, which I suspect is your case.