# Deploy MVC Application to IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller, windows-server-2008-r2, .net-framework-version

I have created a ASP.NET MVC Application with .Net Framework 4.5. I have tried to deploy in IIS 7.5 with Application Pool 4.0 but the following errors. Is there anything I should change in IIS Configuration or in Application Web.conf.

Thanks in advance !

[image: Error 403. Directory Browsing Disabled]

[image: Error 404. Directory Browsing Now is Enabled]

Comment: add `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules> ` in your `config` file and see if it helps

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374957/asp-net-mvc-on-iis-7-5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457773/deploying-asp-mvc-5-app-with-iis-7-5

Comment: I have done that too but is the same result :(

Comment: Edit Permissions - add   IIS_IUSRS

Comment: Is your AppPool Classic or Managed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: @Shammelburg Thanks Looks like it solved His Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following settings for your website in IIS

1) Authentication Mode - Windows or Forms Enabled (as per your web.config)
2) Directory Browsing - Enabled (In fact your 1st screen shot clearly says - On the Directory Browsing page, in the Actions pane, click Enable.)